# Histogram bin totals do not equal to image pixel size

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I have the following EMGU CV code to create a histogram for a grayscale image:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr,
    Byte>(fileNameTextBox.Text).Resize(400, 400,
    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, true);

// Convert to grayscale and filter out noise.
Image<Gray, Byte> gray = img.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();

DenseHistogram dh = new DenseHistogram(256, new RangeF(0, 255));
dh.Calculate(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { gray }, false, null);
float[] valHist = new float[256];           // # of bins: 256
dh.MatND.ManagedArray.CopyTo(valHist, 0);
float total = 0F;
for (int ii = 0; ii < 256; ii++)
{
    total += valHist[ii];
}
MessageBox.Show("Bins total: " + total);
```

I run the above code with the following image (the original image does not contain the border around it - I have added it here for demarcation):

[image]

The image is 384 by 282, which makes 108,288 pixels.  But the total of the contents of the histogram's 256 bins is 4,724 (as shown by the `MessageBox` code).  Shouldn't the total be 108,288?  (Maybe I am missing the fundamentals for the concept of histograms?)

(Disclaimer: I am new to both image processing and EMGU CV, and although I have done research, there are relatively few EMGU questions here on SO, and all the other content on the web seems to be copies of questions here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that I had several errors with the approach above.  I was trying to compute the histogram for an image that had been resized and converted to grayscale, which, of course, had destroyed the specs of the original image!

Beyond that, the fundamental problem is that for histogram processing, an image must first be separated into its channels (Blue, Green, Red).  Otherwise, the possibility for each pixel value is between 0 and 16,581,375 (2<sup>24</sup>), and trying to place each such intensity in its own bin would *potentially* require a matrix of size 2<sup>24</sup> with each item requiring up to 2<sup>17</sup> bits.

The following C# code totals pure white pixels and other pixels.  In this case, the totals come out correct:

```
int pureWhites = 0;
int otherPixels = 0;
int totals = 0;
Bgra tmp;

for (int ii = 0; ii < 282; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = 0; jj < 384; jj++)
    {
        tmp = img[ii,jj];
        if (tmp.Blue == 255 && tmp.Green == 255 && tmp.Red == 255)
            pureWhites++;
        else
            otherPixels++;
    }
}

totals = purewhites + otherPixels;
```

For the image in question (above), the totals are as follows:

> pureWhites: 106,757 (image background)
>   
>   otherPixels: 1,531 (text)
>   
>   totals: 108,288 (correct number of pixels in the image)

I hope this helps others in terms of histogram basics as well as pixel-level access to images in EMGU CV.

Comment: I don't think that you can only get a histogram on RGB pixels. You can perfectly get an histogram for gray value pixels.
I've just went through some of the documentation of the EMGU DenseHistogram class, but couldn't find any errors in your code using that, so probably the error indeed will be within the part where you create/resize/convert your image.

Comment: @RFerwerda Thanks. In my answer above I describe how you can get a histogram (if you really wanted to) for composite pixel values, but you are right in that the typical method is to separate the colors into R,G,B channels.

Comment: @Sabuncu So you do walk around here. ;)

Comment: @karlphillip Thanks for looking around, much appreciated, esp. coming from you.